# Best practice for connecting to Postgres from Django

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I recently installed Postgres 11 on my Raspberry Pi 4, and attempted to connect to a database from my Django app:

`return psycopg2.connect(dbname="covid")`

The connection failed like so:

`Problem with db connection: FATAL:  role "www-data" does not exist`

If I run:

`SELECT rolname, rolsuper FROM pg_roles;`

inside psql or pgAdmin, then indeed `www-data` does not appear in the list. I can see from the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919391/ddg#11919677) that it probably needs an entry in Postgres. If I create a `www-data` role in Postgres, then I get an error stating that permission is denied on the table I'm trying to query. The only way I've found of avoiding that is to give `www-data` superuser privileges.

It doesn't seem wise to give the Apache/Linux web-facing user such wide privileges. If I create some other role inside Postgres, and specify that when making the db connection inside Django, I get an error stating that peer authentication fails. I'm obviously missing something here, and would appreciate insight. Thanks.

Comment: Since it is apparently _your_ application _you_ are the one to know what permissions it needs, no?

Comment: My app needs to be able to read/write records. But as it is a web-facing app exposing itself to Postgres using the Apache username www-data, I want to make sure that I'm securing the connection properly.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but "securing the connection properly" has very little to do with the application role privileges (which are dictated by business requirements). To secure a connection you 1) encrypt it using a reliable method and 2) authenticate it. Once it's secure, you worry about authorisation; this is where the role privileges come in.

Comment: I clarified with an edit to my post, and updated with a new bit of information. If I should be posting on another forum instead like Stack Overflow, I'm happy to move it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a Postgres 101 question. Hint: read the documentation on pg_hba.conf and make appropriate changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might stem from the fact that adding users/roles in PostgreSQL always requires you to GRANT the required privileges to the new user/role for any existing objects in the database. When you assign the `super_user` attribute you are bypassing any issues, because of missing permissions/privileges/grants.

> `SUPERUSER`
> `NOSUPERUSER`
> These clauses determine whether the new role is a "superuser", **who can override all access restrictions** within the database. **Superuser status is dangerous and should be used only when really needed.** You must yourself be a superuser to create a new superuser. If not specified, `NOSUPERUSER` is the default.

<sup>***Reference:** [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-createrole.html) (PostgreSQL | Documentation)*</sup>

## Solution

You would possibly have to follow these basic steps in order to achieve what your are aiming for, depending on your requirements.

### 1. Create Role

```
CREATE ROLE "www-data" WITH PASSWORD 'ThisBetterBe4SecureP@ssword`;
```

<sup>***Reference:** [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-createrole.html) (PostgreSQL | Documentation)*</sup>

This is where you possibly added the `WITH SUPERUSER` addition, which circumvents any issues with any missing GRANTs.

### 2. Grant Access to ...

This is where you are going to have to be a bit more selective in what you assign....

#### a. Table Permissions

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON yourtable TO "www-data";
```

#### b. Database Permissions

```
GRANT CREATE ON yourdatabase TO "www-auth";
```

#### c. Role Permissions

```
GRANT PUBLIC TO "www-auth";
```

This essentially gives `"www-auth"` the privileges assigned to the `PUBLIC` role in the database, if the role were to exist.

> **Hint:**
> Run `\pg+` to see all roles in your PostgreSQL instance.

<sup>***Reference:** [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-grant.html) (PostgreSQL | Documentation)*</sup>

### Conclusion

You are going to have to decide individually which privileges that the role is going to have in your database. The PostgreSQL documentation mentioned in the referenced links will provide you with the relevant information.